# Can I sync a Sharepoint 2013 List with Project Server 2013 List? C# or JavaScript API?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, project-server, sharepoint-apps, ms-project-server-2013

If this is possible, where is the best way?

Creating a SharePoint project or app?

Thanks for help-me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could certainly do it through custom code.  One option would be to write a [event receiver](http://onceinawhilescribble.blogspot.ca/2013/05/creating-simple-event-receiver-in.html) on the SharePoint list that would update the Project Server list using the [Project Server API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms504195.aspx#pj15_Programmability_PSI).  This would give you one way syncing from SharePoint to Project Server, if you want to do two way syncing you would need to create a event handler on the Project server side that would make a call to SharePoint to save the changes back.